# what's the difference between eclipse.ini and run configuration settings about jvm memory?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, jvm

I am facing a memory problem in an application,so I have to set up the right jvm memory arguments e.g `-Xms???m` or `-Xmx???m`.
But I found two way to setup it, first is to setup in the eclipse.ini, the other way is to setup in eclipse's `run configuration---auguments` setting.
But what's the difference between the two way of memory setting, what's the exactly meaning of them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These control different things.

The settings in eclipse.ini control the JVM that Eclipse runs in. They have no effect on programs you run from Eclipse.

Eclipse starts a separate JVM when you run your program. The Run Configuration settings control that JVM. You have a separate Run Configuration for each program so that you can set things differently for each program.